# Duplicate checkboxes when copying a worksheet using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, openxml

I'm using OpenXML 2.5 for duplicating Excel worksheets that contains checkboxes (either form control or ActiveX).  I've followed [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2009/02/19/how-to-copy-a-worksheet-within-a-workbook/) as a starting point.

It works well, however if you duplicate a worksheet that has a checkbox, the duplicated sheet ends up with two checkboxes on top of each other.  You can only see the 2nd checkbox if you move the one on the top aside. The code doesn't particularly do anything to duplicate the checkbox itself ([pastbin](http://pastebin.com/JVKtuC7X)).

I've used the OpenXML Productivity Tool to compare the XML for each sheet.  There are no references to an additional checkbox on the new sheet.

Can you see any reason for getting multiple checkboxes on the worksheet that was  duplicated?

thanks

Comment: `Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();`

I am not sure if this will help you. But, what first child is ?
Are you getting checkbox too ?
Is there a option prepend instead of append for this line :
               `sheets.Append(copiedSheet);`

Comment: That line is just getting a collection of Sheets of the workbook.  How else would you add the new clone to the workbook?  Don't you think the the extra checkbox is already in the copiedSheet object at somepoint before the Append?